# CHAINLINK_VERSION' is not recognized

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

@chainlink/contracts
| Nothing to compile
| No need to generate any newer typings.
Done in 37.75s.
CHAINLINK_VERSION="@22a3c1788eb9bf6d8b099bf8e1a9ee0f6e081eaf" yarn workspace @chainlink/operator-ui build
'CHAINLINK_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [GNUmakefile:49: operator-ui] Error 1

After using the command make install i got the error above

Comment: Hello, could you please add more details to this question and format it with back tiks? Please see this for formating questions on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing my chainlink version and installing it on docker  https://github.com/codertjay/chainlink-docker

Comment: And also I notice the issue was the yarn version . But windows never tells me to use a particular version . So I used docker but also windows wsl worked for me . But it still having issues with my Man windows .